# [__NSArrayI pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

the basic premise of this code is that it has two fields, a textfield that stores the height of the person in feet, and one that stores the height in inches. Thus, when someone clicks the feet textfield or the inches text field, a pickerview pops up that allows the user to pick the height. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
[__NSArrayI pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

When I run the following code:

```
#import "GetUserStatistics.h"

@interface GetUserStatistics ()

@end

@implementation GetUserStatistics

@synthesize feetField, inchesField, pickerViewFeet, pickerViewInches, ftPicker, inPicker;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pickerViewFeet = [self createNumberPickerViewWithStartingValue:1 endingValue:8 defaultValue:5];
    NSLog(@"%f", pickerViewFeet.frame.size.height);
    feetField.inputView = pickerViewFeet;
    NSLog(@"%f", feetField.inputView.frame.size.height);

    //feetField.inputAccessoryView = [self createToolbar];
    pickerViewInches = [self createNumberPickerViewWithStartingValue:0 endingValue:11 defaultValue:8];
    NSLog(@"%f",pickerViewInches.frame.size.height);
    inchesField.inputView = pickerViewInches;
    NSLog(@"%f", inchesField.inputView.frame.size.height);

    //NSLog(@"%@", pickerViewFeet.delegate);
    //inchesField.inputAccessoryView = [self createToolbar];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}

-(void) inputAccessoryViewDidFinish{
    feetField.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", [(UIPickerView *)feetField.inputView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    inchesField.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", [(UIPickerView *)inchesField.inputView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    actualHeight = ([feetField.text intValue])*12 + [inchesField.text intValue];
    NSLog(@"actual height:%i", actualHeight);
    [feetField endEditing:YES];
    [inchesField endEditing:YES];
}
-(UIPickerView *) createNumberPickerViewWithStartingValue: (int) startVal endingValue: (int) endingVal defaultValue: (int) defaultValue{
    UIPickerView * tempPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 150)];
    ftPicker = [[NumberPickerView alloc]initWithStartingValue:startVal endingVal:endingVal];
    tempPicker.delegate = ftPicker;
    [tempPicker selectRow:defaultValue inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    return tempPicker;
}

-(UIToolbar * ) createToolbar{

    UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:
                            CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 44)]; //should code with variables to support view resizing
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                  target:self action:@selector(inputAccessoryViewDidFinish)];


    //using default text field delegate method here, here you could call
    //myTextField.resignFirstResponder to dismiss the views
    [myToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject: doneButton] animated:NO];
    return myToolbar;
}
-(void) addPickerViewToTextField: (UITextField **) textField pickerViewToAdd : (UIPickerView **) pickerView{
    NSLog(@"dading view");

    *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 150)];
}

@end
```

NumberPickerView code (implements the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol):

```
-(NumberPickerView *) initWithStartingValue: (int) startingVal endingVal: (int) endingVal
{
    startingValue = startingVal;
    endingValue = endingVal;
    return self;
}
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"calling this function");
    return endingValue - startingValue + 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", (int)(row) + startingValue];
}
```

I suspect the issue is with the returning of the UIPickerView, specifically that the NumberPickerView is being destroyed after the function returns the view and so the pickerViewFeet no longer has a delegate. I'm not sure if this is the problem, and if it is how to fix this, can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the `ftPicker` property defined? Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: ARC, and defined as:

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NumberPickerView * ftPicker;

Comment: Update your question showing how this `GetUserStatistics` class is used as well as the call to `createNumberPickerViewWithStartingValue`. Perhaps the `GetUserStatistics` instance gets deallocated which means the `ftPicker` gets deallocated.

Comment: Seems like you set picker view datasource/delegate to an NSArray

Comment: You're not calling base `init` in NumberPickerView's `initWithStartingValue:endingVal:` which might cause troubles.

Comment: Alex I tried that but it still gave me the same error. I know the code in NumberPickerView works because the de-abstracted version of this code worked fine, however, when the code was abstracted as such, it started to cause issues.

Comment: first use self.ftPicker instead of ftpicker and
     -(NumberPickerView *) initWithStartingValue: (int) startingVal   endingVal: (int) endingVal
    {
        self =[ [super alloc]init];
        startingValue = startingVal;
        endingValue = endingVal;
        return self;
    }

Comment: Hey rmaddy so the call to createNumberPickerView is in the viewDidLoad function of GetUserStatistics. As to how the GetUserStatistics is used, the view controller itself just contains two textfields which are both connected to the GetUserStatistics as outlets.

Comment: Avinash I changed it to self.ftPicker and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @sourav There's no point to that. It has nothing to do with the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `createNumberPickerViewWithStartingValue` twice. The 2nd call results in `ftPicker` being reset to a new instance of `NumberPickerView`. This means the first instance assigned to the first picker view gets deallocated. And this results in the crash.

You need to reorganize your code so the same instance variable isn't being used to hold the two `NumberPickerView` instances.

You also need a newer tutorial. You shouldn't be calling `@synthesize` in most cases. And all of your references to the property instance variables should be changed to references to the actual property instead.

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue.

Comment: However, just a couple more questions, as I changed the code now so that instead of ftPicker = [[NumberPickerView alloc]initWithStartingValue:startVal endingVal:endingVal]; I have:

 NumberPickerView * tempNumPicker = [[NumberPickerView alloc]initWithStartingValue:startVal endingVal:endingVal];

However, this crashes, and I believe it is because since tempNumPicker is being declared locally, it gets released after the function has been returned. How can I get around this?

Comment: You need a strong reference by using an ivar. But you need a separate ivar for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

first use `self.ftPicker` instead of `ftpicker` and:

```
-(NumberPickerView *) initWithStartingValue: (int) startingVal endingVal:(int) endingVal {
    self = [super init]; 
    startingValue = startingVal;
    endingValue = endingVal;
    return self; 
}
```

Comment: My numberpickerview is defined as:  @interface NumberPickerView : NSObject <UIPickerViewDelegate>, therefore I cannot do [[super alloc] init];

Comment: @user1549792 Yes you can and you must. Though it should be `self = [super init];`.

Comment: My apology, I could not do the alloc, but I could do self = [super init], however, after that it still did not work.